# Which is the best way to perform these multiplications in C

Tags: c

I have this function form a sample code for an energy meter design using MAXIM's [71M6511](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/6845) which is surposed to perform this computation.

```
E = W * 6.6972*10^-13 * VMAX * IMAX (Wh)

VMAX = 600 (but it is stored in the code with a resolution of 0.1 making it 6000)
IMAX = 208 (also stored as 2080)
```

E here is energy in WattHour,

W is the raw value of kilowatt hour measured by the energy chip. The computation converts it to WattHour, based on the equation above supplied in the energy chip's [documentation](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN4740.pdf) (page 77), and returns it as a signed 32bit integer.

Here is the code

```
#define ONE_MILLION (1000000L)
#WATTSCALE 1885L        // 6.6972E-12 * 2^48.

 static U32 Whr (U08x *w)
{                                             // 'w' is a 8-byte quantity.

U08 xdata x[13], y[12];                  // Need extra digit for divide.
    U32 xdata scale;
    U08 xdata t[4+4+1];

    scale = (U32) Vmax * (U32) Imax;          //scale=[Vmax*10E+01] * [Imax*10E+01].
    multiply_8_4 (y, w,(U08x *)&scale);       // y = w * Vmax * Imax * 10E+02.
    scale = WATTSCALE;                        //[LSB * 2^48 * 10E+01]  (10E-03 Wh).
    multiply_8_4 (x + 1, y,(U08x *)&scale);   //[x*2^16] = [y/2^32]*[LSB * 2^48] (mWh)
                                              //..dropped low-order 4-bytes of 'y'.
    scale = ONE_MILLION;                      // Modulo ONE_MILLION.
    divide (x + 1, (U08x *) &scale, 10, 4, t);// x / 1,000,000;
    x[7] = 0;                                 //Clear high order of 4-byte result.
    return (* (U32x *) &x[7]);                // Return 32-bit answer (x % 1,000,000). 
}
```

multiply_8_4() is a function that multiplies an 8byte data (this is the data pointed to by w) by a 4byte data (scale), and places the result in another buffer (in this case buffer x)

I'm just wondering why the simple calculation was (in my opinion) complicated this way with the multiplication and divsion by 2^48 and 2^32 and so on.

Is there any particular reason for this apart for the programmer's choice?

Comment: But its not a simple calculation using integers. At a guess, floats were considered too inaccurate to be useful. Whether that's true or not I've no idea, it's certainly more than possible though.

Comment: Can you step through the code, or log results, so you can determine exactly where you are getting the wrong value?

Comment: @Jay I'm not getting any wrong values, the calculation is correct, i've steped through it. I just want to understand why they had to go through all that trouble to perform the calculation, and if there is any real benefit in their approach which i find very complicated

Answer (score 3):

It appears that they are using an 8-bit microcontroller which doesn't do floating point calculations. They also state that fetching data from memory is more efficient when its done in bytes rather than shorts or ints. The code you show implements a fixed point multiplication with constants and values scaled to provide sufficient room on both sides of the binary point so that overflows don't occur and so that there is sufficient precision for their needs.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason or another the programmer chose/had to do the computations on integers rather than on floating point values. So:

1. He cannot operate on values that have too many significant digits below 1. If you try to store 6.6972*10^-13 as an integer you will get 0. So,6.6972*10^-13 gets multiplied by 2^48 to give 1885.094214... It's probably fine to cut the digits after the dot.
2. NOT

Comment: thanks alot, there was a multiplication by 2^48, and a division by 2^32 (although i still haven't figured out where that division took place), which leaves 2^16 still in the mix. I also didn't get how that 2^16 was removed from the final result. can you help me with that too?

Comment: Ok, frankly looking at it the second time, there isn't any division by 2^32 or multiplication by 2^16. Comments sometimes lie. Discard point 2 in my answer. Notice that the result of divide() is written to address `x+1`, so `(U32x *)x[7]` means "get the value of `x+1` shifted by 6 bytes. 6*8 = 48, so there you go: the value is 'divided' by 2^48 in the `return (* (U32x *) &x[7]);` line.

Comment: What really happens in the second multiply_8_4() is `[x+1] = [y]*[LSB * 2^48] (mWh)`